# Set presentation mode in KUbuntu

Tags: kde, plasma, presentation

I use KDE Plasma as DE, and I can set presentation mode (to prevent sleeping) in settings, I would like to ask you if I can set it in terminal, because I would like to create script for it.

[image: Presentation mode]

Comment: @DK Bose In Display Configuration in System tray.

Comment: @DKBose Here: https://i.imgur.com/9TG8xHn.png

Comment: @DKBose great :)

Comment: @DKBose What do you mean by that Display Configuration icon has to be in one place? Maybe workaround could be that I prolong sleep time to like 1 day.

Comment: @DKBose it not good solution :/ if I change layout I would have to change it, so is possible to change that time when system logs out you from terminal?

Comment: Yes that is what I all want.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about "evdev" or the usage you've described in your latest comment. I'll delete this answer since it doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# To set presentation mode
inhibit_cookie=$(qdbus org.freedesktop.PowerManagement.Inhibit /org/freedesktop/PowerManagement/Inhibit org.freedesktop.PowerManagement.Inhibit.Inhibit "a name" "a reason")

# To unset presentation mode
qdbus org.freedesktop.PowerManagement.Inhibit /org/freedesktop/PowerManagement/Inhibit org.freedesktop.PowerManagement.Inhibit.UnInhibit $inhibit_cookie
```

Comment: I will get: `Method name '1' is not a valid member name.`

Comment: I updated it to make it work, I forgot the second part of the first command.

Comment: Thank you very much :)